# Gradle fetching wrong libraries version for Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle

The short one. This is the part of dependencies connected with Spring that I have

```
project.ext.set("libraries", "")

def springVersion = '3.2.2.RELEASE'
def springSecurityVersion = '4.0.1.RELEASE'

project.libraries = [
        apacheCommonsDbcp: 'org.apache.commons:com.springsource.org.apache.commons.dbcp:1.2.2.osgi',
        tomcatJdbc: 'org.apache.tomcat:com.springsource.org.apache.tomcat.jdbc:1.0.9.3',
        springCore: "org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion",
        springWeb: "org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.14.RELEASE",
        springWebMvc: "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion",
        springBeans: "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion",
        springContext: "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion",
        springContextSupport: "org.springframework:spring-context-support:$springVersion",
        springTx: "org.springframework:spring-tx:$springVersion",
        springOxm: "org.springframework:spring-oxm:$springVersion",
        springOrm: "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion",
        springDataJpa: "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.2.0.RELEASE",
        springAop: "org.springframework:spring-aop:$springVersion",
        springSecurityCore: "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:$springSecurityVersion",
        springSecurityWeb: "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:$springSecurityVersion",
        springSecurityConfig: "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:$springSecurityVersion",
        springTest: "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion",
        cucumberSpring: 'info.cukes:cucumber-spring:1.0.8',
        metricsSpring: "com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:3.0.3"
]
```

The question is why for gods sake after building project, I see

spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE

spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE

spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE

spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE

in external objects of my project?
Please notice that spring web is only of 4.1.6. for core there are several versions
Would appreciate any detailed explanation.

Comment: Did you try the command line option `--refresh-dependencies`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have some dependencies that in turn depend on older version of sprint-core. Use `gradle dependencies` to print a tree of all dependencies, including transitive ones. There, you should be able to trace which library is pulling in which one.